# Is there a framework in apache spark to send message in a JMS queue?

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to use Apache Spark in order to treat data in my data base. When i detect a specific behaviou I want to trigger an event (such an alarm) to notify some users. One way would be to feed an JMS queue accessible by my users.

Therefore, is there a framework in apache spark to send message in a JMS queue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no inbuilt frame work but you can use forEachPartitions method to send the data to external systems, below is the sample code

```
input.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition(
      partitionOfRecords =>
        {
          // Create Jms queue  Connection Here 

            partitionOfRecords.foreach( messgae => 
            {
                    jsmQueueConnection.send(message)

            }
          )

      }))
```